# Ternary Operator in Java

Tags: java, recursion, ternary-operator

I'm trying to learn Java using my knowledge I have gained from programming in C. In C, I loved the ternary operation. I'm trying to apply this in Java but I'm not sure if I'm doing it correctly. For the following recursive method that sums the from `1` to `n`, I have the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    int n = 6;
    System.out.printf("sum of %d is %d ", n, new learn().sum(n));
}

public int sum(int num){
    int result;
    result = (num == 1) ? result = 1 : result = num + sum(num - 1);
}
```

which is giving me an error by stating that `+` is undefined. If someone could point out where my mistake is at, that would be much appreciated!

Comment: `sum` has a return type of `void`.

Comment: It works, but it is wrong - in Java as well as C.

Comment: You shouldn't edit it in-place. That kind of changes everything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `sum` method currently has a return type of `void`. It therefore cannot return anything. In that case, you cannot be using the method invocation expression as a value, as you do in

```
num + sum(..)
// or in
System.out.printf("sum of %d is %d ", n, new learn().sum(n));
```

Change it to

```
public int sum(int num) {
    return (num == 1) ? 1 : num + sum(num - 1);
}
```

to get the behavior you want.

Assigning `result` within the ternary expression when you are assigning to it outside of the ternary expression is completely pointless since you can't use the intermediary assignment.

Answer (score 0):

That wouldn't be correct in C, either. The ternary operator evaluates to the selected expression, so don't assign inside it (just assign the result), and you clearly intend your method to return an `int`. Change the return type and `return result` (or eliminate the variable entirely and just return the value of the ternary expression).

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
result = (num == 1) ? result = 1 : result = num + sum(num - 1);
```

To:

```
result = (num == 1) ? 1 : num + sum(num - 1);
```

What is inside the operators ?: are the possible values of "result".